# ExpandableListView - Keep the title of the group visible until the group dissapear

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've been searching a while, but i can't find any clue, so maybe someone can help me here.

I'm using ExpandableListView in android to show my info ordered in groups, and everything works great.., the problem is that is common that the group has more than 20 elements, so when I scroll down the list, the title of the group goes up further the screen, and of course, it dissapears. My client says that in iPhone, it is possible to keep the title of the group on the top of list until the last element of the group dissapear when the user scroll up the list, so he wants the same functionality in android. I'm trying to find something like that, but I can't find anything.

Does anybody knows it this behavior is possible to do in android.

Thanks a lot.

(And sorry about my English.. i need to improve it a lot  ):(

Comment: This feature of the iOS SDK is very nice, but I don't know how to do that on android.
I know how to put the title group on the first position of the list, every time the user click on the group, but when the user scroll down the title up the title goes up. If you wanna this I can show.

Comment: Thanks, it could work. I can figure out now how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Yotes did you found any solution for this problem?